# iVar getter / method with same name?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can anyone explain what is happening here, at first glance I would consider this to be bad practice. My question is: in the example below am I creating a new getter for model with -(id)model (i.e. overwriting the original from the @property), or am I just masking the @property getter with this new same named method?

```
@implementation PlanetController
@synthesize model;
@synthesize planetLabel_01;
@synthesize planetLabel_02;
@synthesize planetLabel_03;

- (id)model {
    if(!model) {
        PlanetModel *tempModel = [[PlanetModel alloc] init];
        [self setModel:tempModel];
        [tempModel release];
    }
    return model;
}
```

Does that make sense?

gary.

Comment: you probably want to use `@property (getter=model) id model` but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is not bad practice. You are not overwriting or masking anything. @synthesize will only synthesize what's needed. In this case, the setter.

Answer (score 2):

As everybody else has said, that's absolutely fine.  Your model method is used instead of the synthesized one.

However be cautious: you have implemented a method that is not atomic so your property should have the following declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id model;
```

otherwise it is lying about its implementation.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I have it decleared as:@property (nonatomic, retain) PlanetModel *model; is that too specific and I should be using id as in your example?

Comment: Ah I see, to match "- (id)model {" I guess my previous comment would be fine if I changed the getter to "- (PlanetModel *)model {"

Answer (score 0):

You've implemented your own accessor for the *model* property. That's a perfectly valid thing to do. You can verify that it's your implementation that is executed when you do either `aPlanetController.model` or `[aPlanetController model]`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks OK to me, but you can always check it by printing out the method names at run-time.

```
#import <objc/objc.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#include "SFUtility.h"

/*!
 @abstract spits out the objc/runtime.h information for the class
 */
void SFInvestigateOBJC(id obj) {


    unsigned int total_method_count = 0;
    Method * method_list = class_copyMethodList(object_getClass([obj class]), &total_method_count);
    @try
    {
        SFLog(@"ClassName: %s", class_getName(object_getClass([obj class])));
        SFLog(@"ClassName: %@", [obj class]);
        uint method_counter = 0;
        for (method_counter = 0; method_counter < total_method_count; method_counter++)
        {
            Method method = method_list[method_counter];
            // check if method the KVC getter you are interested in
            SFLog(@"Method: %s", sel_getName(method_getName(method)));
        }
        NSDictionary *props = [[obj entity] propertiesByName];
        for (NSString *s in [props allKeys]) {
            SFLog(@"KVC: %@", s);
        }
    } @catch (NSException *e) {
        SFError(@"Exception: %@", [e description]);
    }

    @try {
        SFLog(@"Entity: %@",[[obj entity] name]);
        SFLog(@"EntityClassName: %@", [[obj entity] managedObjectClassName]);
    } @catch (NSException * e) {
        SFError(@"Exception: %@", [e description]);
    }

}
```